# Downsides using front-end frameworks for API handling? Performance and security

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

So, while practising all the new tech. Angular 2, AngularJS, Firebase, Loopback, NodeJS etc .. I'm kind of confused on some topics that people don't really talk about. It might go into too much detail, but I'll try to split it as much as I can.

**Part 1 -- Performance**

I like the approach of: MyApp (Web, Mobile, ..) --> API <-- Database
Okay, we perform API requests to the same server over HTTP which is slower, but for small projects this should be a non issue right? Or are there any other solutions for this matter?

I know they often just do: MyApp --> Framework <-- Database and add an API interface which calls the correct actions to get the necessary logic/data out to eg. a mobile app

**-- End Part 1**

**Part 2 -- Security**

So, assume we have an API up and running either with Lumen, LoopBack or anything else like a realtime Firebase database (not really an API). Then we can connect with it over HTTP requests via Angular, jQuery... If a user inspects our source code, they can easily see how we handle data in the backend. How can this be secured in a way that only the necessary applications have control over the API (OAuth2 ?) and also that we limit the insight of users into our API.

**-- End Part 2**

Thanks.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's just matter of visualisation. Let's say it's just Laravel or Lumen. That is not the point of the question. The API simply brings out actions to the public of an existing framework. But you can work without the framework and make the API handle everything.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. I thought the question was about front-end frameworks. Laravel isn't one, is it?

Comment: In any case, the question is waaaaay too broad.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ofcourse Laravel isn't a front-end framework. But you can access an API that is built around Laravel with any front-end framework. This is more complex matter then just build an API. It should be secure and performant. Even while using a front-end framework where a user can check the source code of the API calls.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please stop posting unuseful comments. This isn't helpful at all. There isn't much documentation on this topic available.

Comment: Oh, and for the future, ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I thought, it's a "too broad" question, but actually, it has a short answer.

### Performance

Irrelevant. If you gotta fetch data, you gotta fetch data. Be it API call or some custom action in your laravel code (or something). Same HTTP stuff.

### Security

> ... where a user can check the source code of the API calls.

Security through obscurity doesn't work. Always consider that your client is compromised. Use proper authentication/authorization methods (OAuth and the like). So even if a malicious user *knows* (which he will) your api endpoint signatures (or whatever you were trying to hide), he can't abuse them.